# How to slice the element Address.line?

Tags: hl7-fhir

it is possible to slice a string list, like the element line on the Address? I'm trying to do something like that: https://simplifier.net/redenacionaldedadosemsaude/brendereco, but when I generate my IG, my sample resource does not validate the lines.

my resourse example address element:

```
<address>        
    <use value="home"/>
    <type value="physical"/>
    <text value="1003 Healthcare Drive, Northfield MN" />
    <line value="street"/>
    <line value="Healthcare Drive"/>
    <line value="1003"/>
    <line value="neighborhood"/>
    <city value="Northfield"/>
    <state value="MN"/>        
    <postalCode value="12345123" />
    <country value="Brasil" />
</address>
```

Errors I got on my IG:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you slice and declare a discriminator, then every slice needs to establish a value for that discriminator.  You sliced by Address.line.value by value.  That means that each line slice needs to specify a required value set binding, a fixed value or a pattern.  (And the constraints declared by each slice can't overlap.)  You only declared a required binding on one of the slices.  The street, number, complement and neighborhood slices are unconstrained.  That's not allowed.

Given that, realistically, you *can't* define value sets (let alone fixed values or patterns) for those elements, I don't think slicing is going to be possible with just 'value'.  If you need to distinguish between different repetitions of Address.line, you're going to need to put an extension on them that indicates what type of line they are.

Also, it's not clear that you're using 'line' correctly.  An address line is a string of text that appears on a separate line.  It's not just a distinct part of the address.  Unless streetType, street, number, complement, etc. all need to appear on separate lines, you can't create separate repetitions of 'line' for them.  If you want to break out the parts of the address, you need to use extensions.  There are already standard extensions for most 'parts' of an address - you can see them here: https://build.fhir.org/datatypes-extras.html#Address